Client secret expiry-"Azure Container Registry" Type of Service Connection in Azure DevOps
I am trying to create a new Service Connection for using in my pipeline in Azure DevOps using the GUI with
Container Registry type but the corresponding service principal client secret has an automatic expiry for only 3 months which will then need renewal again. Can we in some way create a service principal from the GUI itself which will have a longer validity, maybe for a year.
Type of service connection I am creating
I tried creating a new client secret for the service principal but the pipeline fails if I do not create a new Service connection in itself so need to understand how to have a service principal with longer validity automatically

The expiration date of the client secret is managed in AAD tenant, Azure DevOps cannot provide any built-in option to change the expiration date.
When the client secret for a service connection is expired, you can open the service connection in Azure DevOps and try to update any field on it, such "Description" or "Service connection name", and then save the update. Once updated, it will try to generate a new client secret for use.

Can this be automated, otherwise it has to be done manually every 3 months

Have you tried this? Creating a long expire time AAD application secret
$startDate = Get-Date
$endDate = $startDate.AddYears(99)
$aadAppsecret = New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId xxx-xxx-111-222-xxx -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate

I have created one for a long expires:


Can you explain how this can be used with the docker registry service connection type in the Pipelines Service connections tab? For example how do you link the long expire application secret to the service connection?
